# jQuery UI Tabs - Multiple instances linking to same DIV set

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

```
Note: I want to use .tabs() and avoid NOT using .tabs(), and writing everything 
separately to handle the fades and tab selections like others have found.
```

As the title suggests, I want to have a list of tabs in *two seperate positions* on the page, but I want them *to work together with the same data*.

The problem is that setting up two ul's with `nav` classes causes conflicts and so two tabs can be selected at once: one on the left and one on the right.

[image: Tabs Problem]
*See how each tab set isn't working together and can be selected separately?*

**Code for a working single set of tabs**

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <!-- Tab data gets inserted here -->
    <div id="overlay"><div class="overlay"></div></div>

    <!-- First Tab Set -->
    <!-- NOTE: This will appear on the left -->
    <div class="navigation nav-left">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li>Link1</li>
            <li>Link2</li>
        </ul>
   </div>

   <!-- Data for the tabs - this works! -->
   <div id="container">
       <!-- Link 1 Tab -->
       <div>This is data for Link 1</div>
       <div>This is data for Link 2</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**The jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $("ul.nav").tabs("div#container > div", {
    effect: 'fade',
    fadeOutSpeed: "500"});
});
```

As you can see, the above jQuery sets tabs up for `ul.nav` linking to each div within `#container` individually. This single set of tabs on the left hand side of my page works!

**The Hard Part**

How do I change this to allow for **two** sets of tabs on my page?

I want a second `<div class="navigation nav-right">` -- *note the nav-right* to hold these tabs on the right hand side of the page.

This second set of tabs must work *alongside* the first set, so only one tab can be active at once, and cancels out other tab selections.

**My code causing the two tab sets concurrency problem**

**HTML**

```
    <!-- First Tab Set -->
    <!-- NOTE: This will appear on the left -->
    <div class="navigation nav-left">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li>Link1</li>
            <li>Link2</li>
        </ul>
   </div>

   <!-- Second Tab Set (Attempt) -->
   <!-- NOTE: I want nav-right here -->
   <div class="navigation nav-right">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li>Link1</li>
            <li>Link2</li>
        </ul>
   </div>

   <!-- Data for the tabs -->
   <div id="container">
       <!-- Link 1 Tab -->
       <div>This is data for Link 1</div>
       <div>This is data for Link 2</div>
       . . .
       <div>This is data for Link 5</div>
   </div>
```

**Final Thought**

I was rather hoping to not have to write my own jQuery Tabs function with `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` - what can I do to make this work?

Comment: If you don't want to write code your own, why not file a customer support/feature request with the vendor of `.tabs()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the vendor of `.tabs()` - he "can't be bothered" with updating for multiple instances of tabs linking to the same DIV set.

My only option was to roll my own code, completely doing away with `.tabs()` and performing my own `.fadeOut()`, `.fadeIn()` and `.load()` functions combined within a large function call.

The upside of this is that I know exactly how it all works and can add to it easily in the future, and I recommend spending a little time (it's not going to take too long) to do it yourself.

If the owner ever does decide to include this functionality, I will update my post, but as of early 2013, there isn't currently a way to use the `.tabs()` plugin in this way.